# How to go against near end game all for one tactics?

Tags: die2nite

So our towns basically in real chaos.  12 people have died, 3 people have started selfish play, upgrading to hovels and shacks, having defensive items hoarded up in their house.

Now one of them is banished, but we lack the remaining active members to banish the other ones. Checking their souls, it seems like they have done this before to obtain Last Man Standing.

The reason for the two not banished ones is that everyone else started stealing first (everyone else = 2 people) and that the town was doomed anyway.

So I would like to prevent these people from becoming too strong and becoming the last man standing.

Now we so far only survived 2 attacks and I believe you need to survive 5 to get a reward for last man standing, but are there any ways I can prevent these people from getting the town down further?

Comment: Wow, they started end game in day _2?_

Comment: well, during the second day, the more expierienced players just looted the bank and started building their defences. I just watched out of the gates until someone decided to close the gates at 22.59.

Comment: I died in the night only 2 people lived. our zombies spiked :O. 24,24,118.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by badp, the possible solutions

- Wait for them to go outside, and shut the gates. Don't open them until the next day.
- 1. Shun them all.
  2. Build a pump.
  3. Transfer water in the bank like crazy.

  In a few days, they'll be begging you.

  If you don't think you can manage to do so, just spend a night in the desert and start a new life in a different city. If they survive, they won't get to join you in your new town. :)
- While building a hovel is apparently a bannable offense in some towns, it isn't really that detrimental to the town, and you aren't going to accomplish much by banning them. Once they're shunned, they're unlikely to contribute items to the bank (since they can't retrieve them at all) and can't work on construction sites or the workshop. So effectively their AP is useless and that just makes it harder for your town to survive.

  If you really want your town to survive for a while longer, tell them that they can get hero time for last man standing if they help the town survive to day 5. Then detail what you need them to do to help accomplish that. Hopefully the rest of your town will pitch in as well.

  Remember, this is an apocalypse game. People do crazy stuff in an apocalypse. Rather than shunning people immediately, you need to work to find ways to keep them as productive members of the community.

Answer (score 6):

Wait for them to go outside, and shut the gates.   Don't open them until the next day.

Comment: that is ingenously evil.

Comment: You can set it up with the other residents through private messages.

Answer (score 4):

While building a hovel is apparently a bannable offense in some towns, it isn't really that detrimental to the town, and you aren't going to accomplish much by banning them.  Once they're shunned, they're unlikely to contribute items to the bank (since they can't retrieve them at all) and can't work on construction sites or the workshop.  So effectively their AP is useless and that just makes it harder for your town to survive.

If you really want your town to survive for a while longer, tell them that they can get hero time for last man standing if they help the town survive to day 5.  Then detail what you need them to do to help accomplish that.  Hopefully the rest of your town will pitch in as well.

Remember, this is an apocalypse game.  People do crazy stuff in an apocalypse.  Rather than shunning people immediately, you need to work to find ways to keep them as productive members of the community.

Comment: i tought they could stil put things in the bank, not remove them.

Comment: It _is_ detrimental. You are spending 4 AP and a plank into your own defense, while you could spend them in your city's. Complaints are a powerful way to make people act responsibly.

Comment: Yah, but in the grand scheme, I'd much rather have someone waste 4 AP and a plank, and then see what else they can do to help the city, rather than ban them from using their AP ever again.  I've yet to see someone change their behavior as a result of a complaint.

Comment: I agree you should avoid shunning if you can help it.

Comment: @Andy I wasn't sure on that, I updated to say that they're unlikely to contribute to the bank.

Comment: Point taken, even if they can put items in the bank, there is no reason.

Comment: I was banished in my second town, and was still a very active scavenger, but other players may not be so welcome to help.

Comment: @bwarner: I've a new player build a hovel, get a complaint, apologise, and then go-on to be a productive member of the short-lived town... I think it can work if you nip it in the bud.

Answer (score 1):

1. Shun them all.
2. Build a pump.
3. Transfer water in the bank like crazy.

In a few days, they'll be begging you.

If you don't think you can manage to do so, just spend a night in the desert and start a new life in a different city. If they survive, they won't get to join you in your new town. :)

Comment: Warning: in the future this won't be as effective due to the revolt system.

Comment: if i do decide to restart, would it be better to delete my account and make a new one with a refferal? its my first life so i doubt i'd loose much, and it could help a fellow survivor.

Comment: @Andy No, referrals don't help you join cities with people you know. You want Coalitions for that. (What referrals _do_ is give your refferer a discount on hero days should you purchase them.)

Comment: if we all die tonight, i will end up in their citys again with high likelyhood? the problem with the suicide option is that i do not believe in it being a solution.

Comment: @Andy if that happens you can simply wait for them to join a city, wait for that city to get 40 citizens, and only then join one yourself. This ensures you won't be playing with them.

Comment: can you see if they have joined a town and how many people is in that town? if i check my own soul page, there is no info on my current town.  Also, is joining a town after the attack a good chance to have active members? and not first time players?

Comment: @Andy After you die you don't join a new town straight away. You can linger on the town lists and see who is in each town. If you want active players you'll need to stick around some more -- once you do hit 100 soul points, you'll get to have access to advanced cities :)

Comment: You guys are forgetting the most important factor though:  This is how the game was meant to be played!  I mean, sure, it might not sound fun to deal with selfish players, but can you imagine a **real** zombie apocalypse being very fun??

Comment: @GnomeSlice: i did not forget that. but just because of that, i would like to saotage their attempts, rather then kill myself. i do not see this as a bug or people using an exploit. but it is equally part of the game to be against it and steal stuff from them. And a part of me thinks fun wouldn't die with the zombie apocalypse. i have read the survival guide so i am prepared :D.

Comment: Gnome is right that it is part of the game, but Andy is correspondingly entitled to foil their fun. And good luck to him, too!